# Failing to pass requests from nginx (not in a container) to an app in a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am failing in passing requests through nginx (not in a container) to an app in a docker conainer. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong, pls?

workdir/Dockerfile: https://hatebin.com/lmktfzmvkm

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod a+x run.sh
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "-m", "yoomoney_payment_form"]
```

workdir/yoomoney_payment_form/__main__.py: https://hatebin.com/qmqtqqwtgv

```
from jinja2 import Template
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.request import Request
from sanic.response import html, HTTPResponse, text

from .config import HOST, PORT


async def payment_form(request: Request, payment_id: int) -> HTTPResponse:
    return text("Success", 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Sanic(__name__)
    app.add_route(payment_form, "/payment_form/<payment_id:int>")
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT)  # HOST == "127.0.0.1", PORT == 7772
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default: https://hatebin.com/clnrnsjirj

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}


server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name 188.225.76.***;

        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        # yookassa widget payment form
        location /payment_form/ {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7772/payment_form/;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf: http://hastebin.com/hepaqifeme.nginx

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

cmd: `sudo docker run -d -p 7772:7772 -v "$(pwd)"/db.sqlite3:/app/db.sqlite3 -v "$(pwd)"/config.ini:/app/config.ini hello`

docker container logs: https://hatebin.com/itktjijcuu

```
2021-10-18 17:25:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://127.0.0.1:7772
[2021-10-18 17:25:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting worker [1]
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log: https://hastebin.com/qotuwecihu.lua  # logs, that are shown when I try to make a request

```
2021/10/18 20:32:57 [error] 10613#10613: *110 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.243.182.***, server: 188.225.76.***, request: "GET /payment_form/1 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:7772/payment_form/1", host: "188.225.76.***"
2021/10/18 20:32:57 [error] 10613#10613: *112 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.243.182.***, server: 188.225.76.***, request: "GET /robots.txt?1634578377659 HTTP/1.1", host: "188.225.76.***"
2021/10/18 20:32:57 [error] 10613#10613: *110 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 188.243.182.***, server: 188.225.76.***, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "188.225.76.***", referrer: "https://188.225.76.***/payment_form/1"
```

Everything works fine if I add `—network="host"` to docker run cmd, but I don't like it this way.

Request path to reproduce is /payment_form/1 with GET.

P.S.: hastebin is being used in places where hatebin is failing to save the text for some reason, lol

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve] in the question itself, not behind links.  That `docker run` command doesn't look like it should invoke an Nginx but it's hard to tell based on what you've included in the question.

Comment: Can you request directly your container ? Are you sure it is up and not exiting after some error ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze the only thing left to complete a minimal reproducible example is to make the program return anything on a request. I'll edit it. BTW, I already found solution

Comment: @Brewal yes, I added logs of the container :) BTW, I already found solution

Comment: @DavidMaze I added the code in here. That docker run shouldn't invoke a Nginx. As I said on the start of the question, Nginx is not dockerized.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve this problem for several hours. And after I created a question in here, I solved it in 15 minutes, as usual xD
Turns out, the app in container should be ran on 172.17.0.2 (this ip may be different, it may be checked with `docker container inspect <container_id>`) or 0.0.0.0